# Return SweetAlert2 email value

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

How can i return a value (email) after clicking OK for further uses ? 
If its not possible let me know.

I use onClick to call it:

```
<script>
function reward1() {      
    swal({
        title: 'Claim reward ($2)',
        text: 'Please enter your PayPal email address.',
        input: 'email',
        imageUrl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/08/21/29/paypal-3384015_960_720.png',
        imageWidth: 100,
        imageHeight: 100,
        imageAlt: 'Custom image',  
        buttonsStyling: false,
        heightAuto: false
    })    
}    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sweetalert inputs provide a Promise with the value of the input:

```
swal({
  content: 'input'
}).then((value) => {
  this.email = value;
})
```